# What is the solution to "Query " is corrupt" error after latest windows security update

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a large MS Access application that has been running well for 10 years until the last (non-removable) security update from Microsoft. I'm designing with Access 2016 on Windows 10. I compile the app in Access 2013 distribute it with the Access 2013 run-time.
Yesterday my application ran normally in design mode, today keep bumping into the same Query '' is corrupt message for queries that otherwise are fine..
e.g. "UPDATE BillOfPartsLOCAL Set Kit='Glass' where isnull(Kit)"

I should add that many other queries, simple and complex run without any problems

The table "BillOfPartsLOCAL" checks out as normal and the field "Kit" contains nulls.

No code changed at all.
Had the same issue 2 days back on run-time versions of the application and this was caused by SP KB4484119 - removal of this service pack sorted the problem.

Any help on this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the help - Although this was my first post, I've visited StackOverflow many time over the years for help and as always this community comes through!